# Azure Front Door Backend Pool pointing to Azure Load Balancer Public IP not resolving

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, azure-front-door

I have an `Azure Load Balancer` which is configured with an internet facing public IP. I can confirm I can access this public IP from my browser.

**My end goal** is to configure `Azure Front Door` CDN so that it uses the IP from the Load Balancer and at the end of the day I would want to access my load balancer through the Front Door DNS.

I have created the Front Door, I configured a Backend Pool with selecting the option `Public IP Address` as the type, I locate the Load Balancer `Public IP` name from the drop-down, leave everything else to default. I then configure the HTTP and HTTPS routing rules.

I check everything is enabled and then I hit the `Azure Front Door DNS` entry.

According to the FAQ [it should work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#can-we-deploy-azure-load-balancer-behind-front-door) . I keep getting the following error:

```
Our services aren't available right now
We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.
```

However, if I use a separate DNS entry that points to the same IP and with SSL enabled - and then put that DNS entry in Azure Front Door(instead of the IP) - then accessing the web app through FrontDoor works.

Any insight appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out FD wasn't working because of SSL validation error - trying in Postman and turning SSL validation setting off resolves the IP directly.